# how to hide complete URL in browser address bar

Tags: asp.net

I want to hide the sub directory and page information from my asp.net website URL. For example instead of displaying http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479015.aspx I want to display something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/ always in user's browser address bar.

Comment: I have tried URL re-write but it is giving me error.

Comment: You don't have that kind of control of the browser.

Comment: Not in a literal sense, but there are ways to accomplish his goal Oded

Answer (score 1):

This requires a modern browser with History API support

```
 history.pushState({}, false, "/");
```

If you call that on document load, you should achieve the desired effect

More information:

[Manipulating the browser history | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to save your current handler information in a cookie, then in your global asax BeginRequest, and use `HttpContext.Current.RemapHandler` to remap their request to a different handler based on that cookie. Another way is to make use of an iframe on your page, this would be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't think this is good style you can insert your pages into a frame (or iframe):

Start page of your domain, f.e. http://msdn.microsoft.com/:

```
<frameset rows="100%">
    <frame src="/realstartpage.htm">
</frameset>
```

Now when the user navigates to another page, the address bar will not change because only the content of the frame is updated. Be aware that links to pages outside of your website should target the outermost frame:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_top">Stackoverflow</a>
```

But when a user comes in via a direct link to  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479015.aspx then you would be required to forward to http://msdn.microsoft.com/ by a script and create the frameset (or iframe) f.e. by handling an URL parameter on the server.